# My php code shows up as text and wont run

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to make something where you type something into the input field and it will send that information to my database in "tabell". However when i try to run it the php code will show up on the site and not run.

Code:

```
<form name="form" action="" method="get">
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" value="First Name">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" 
       value="Submit"/>
</form>






<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "philip123";
$dbname = "testing";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$value = "$_GET['firstname']

$sql = "INSERT INTO tabell (firstname)
VALUES ($value)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

I have also had this excact problem when trying to fetch data from a database when using multiple scripts. All had the same problem. Using ubuntu 16.04 and php7

Comment: Well, for starters, you've got a pretty glaring syntax error that any decent IDE would point out `$value = "$_GET['firstname']`

Comment: Yeah, i was trying stuff out. I have also tried just inserting data with just 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO MyGuests (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

But same problem. I have tried multiple different scripts but some code seems to show on the site and not load as a script. So just look behind that :)

Comment: You need to load the PHP module and configure it correctly or as far as your server's concerned these are just text files.

Comment: When developing code that may contain critical security bugs, please, please do not link to the site in your question. You're just asking for trouble.

Comment: Also do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== true`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant and in some cases can cause bugs.

Comment: @tadman I'm just using the vps for coding stuff. Nothing private will be put out and if im going to code something that will contain private stuff ill make a new vps :)

Comment: It's really not relevant to the question anyway. Focus on the code and the problems in the code, not where it happens to be deployed at this moment.

Comment: Thats what im trying to do. But nothing seems to work with any of the scripts :/

Answer (score 0):

You need a "; at the end of $values. 
Also, i would recommend PDO :) 
Have fun coding